# dismiss viewController always trigger viewDidLoad and never viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, dismiss

I have a tab bar, in the last tab I have a UIViewController A, that have a button inside, and when you tap on it it is presenting an UIViewController B :

```
let bVC = B()
bVC.settingsPresenter = self   
self.present(bVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When the user is in B and wants to get out of the screen, there is a button that calls this method on A (not B) :

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

So when I arrive on the tab for the first time, it calls viewDidLoad then viewWillAppear on A.
If I go to the first tab then come back to the last, only viewWillAppear on A. Everything looks normal.

But when I dismiss B, viewDidLoad of A is called, and not even viewWillAppear... how can I make it the inverse (you know the logical way as the view is already loaded and I only need to be notify that the tab will appear)

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

if the ViewController is loading but showing another one, it will never view will appear as the other view controller it is presenting will appear

Hope this helps!